# Angular Js Ui-routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I currently working multiple Html page using Angular-Breadcrumbs  and UI-Router.multiple  html page with java script file is not excuting  at the time using of angular routing .only html page is executing......

so , I want to tell 
if u r including java script or angular script function in html page ,only html page is executing not executed java script function

. I have been searching all day and have tried various solutions but nothing has worked.

Is there any solution for this problem  replay with example .....Thank you.

Comment: Please post the exact issue. Refer- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: by using ui-router multiple html page is displaying but if u include angular function inside body tag ..not executing angular js function

Comment: i am using multiple page for ui-routing if I  include any javascript or angular js function in side html page ,so only executing html page not executing js function .....PLZ replay any suggestion ......

Comment: plz share example using ui-breadcrumbs